# add value to multidimensional array after creating an array from a string

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Okay this might be confusing. I'm trying to make a config class for myself and I want its usage to be something like this:

```
$this->config->add('world', 'hello');
// This will create array('hello' => 'world')
```

Now my question is, if I want to add my value into a multi-dimensional array that doesn't exists but would like to create it using something like this:

```
$this->config->add('my value', 'hello => world');
// This should create array('hello' => array('world' => 'my value'))

$this->config->add('my value', 'hello => world => again');
// This should create array('hello' => array('world' => array('again' =>'my value')))
```

I'm having trouble converting `'hello => world'` into an array with the value set to the last array element.

This is what I have so far.

```
    public function add($val, $key = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key))
        {
            $this->_config = $val;

        } else {

            $key = explode('=>', str_replace(' ', '', $key));

            if (count($key) > 1)
            {
                // ?

            } else {

                if (array_key_exists($key[0], $this->_config))
                {
                    $this->_config[$key[0]][] = $val;

                } else {

                    $this->_config[$key[0] = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function add($val, $key = null)
{
    $config=array();
    if (is_null($key))
    {
        $this->config = $val;

    } else {
        $key = explode('=>', str_replace(' ', '', $key));
        $current=&$this->config;
        $c=count($key);
        $i=0;
        foreach($key as $k)
        {
            $i++;
            if($i==$c)
            {
                $current[$k]=$val;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!isset($current[$k]) || !is_array($current[$k])) $current[$k]=array();
                $current=&$current[$k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a recursive version, It will be more resource-expensive:

```
public function add($val, $key = null)
{
    $this->config=array();
    if (is_null($key))
    {
        $config = $val;
    } else {
        $key = array_reverse(explode('=>', str_replace(' ', '', $key)));
        self::addHelper($val,$key,$config);
    }
}
private static function addHelper(&$val,&$keys,&$current)
{
    $k=array_pop($keys);
    if(count($keys)>0)
    {
        if(!isset($current[$k]) || !is_array($current[$k])) $current[$k]=array();
        addHelper(&$val,$keys,&$current[$k]);
    }
    else $current[$k]=$val;
}
```

Comment: hmmm, nice! but how can this be done in a recursive scenario?

Comment: I just tested it and made some revisions.

Comment: You want this as a recursive function? The foreach loop recurses into the array structure. `add('test','a=>very=>nested=>array');` produces `array(1) { ["a"]=> array(1) { ["very"]=> array(1) { ["nested"]=> &array(1) { ["array"]=> string(4) "test" } } } }`

Comment: Added a recursive version. I recommend the first one - it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but it will wipe other data in $this->_config

```
... more code
if (count($key) > 1)
{
// ?
    $i = count($key) - 1;
    while($i >= 0) {
        $val = array($key[$i] => $val);
        $i--;
    }

    $this->_config = $val;
}
... more code
```

Comment: good approach, i would want to use this in a recursive form and also if a parent element exists then append the array into that element.